# Firestore .set method results in new ID every time for my object - Need solution

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Firestore and Dart, and I'm encountering a problem related to the creation of document IDs. Every time I use the .set() method to modify a document, a new document gets created because the ID field (id) of MyObject returns null.

Here's a simplified example of my current code:

```dart
class ObjectOverview extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _State extends State<ObjectOverview> {
  List<MyObject> objects = [];
  ...
  trailing: Row(
    ...
    await widget.firestoreService.setMyObject(objects[index]);
  );
}

class FirestoreService {
  ...
  Future<void> setMyObject(MyObject myObject) async {
    await _firestore.collection('my_objects').doc(myObject.id).set(myObject.toJson());
  }
}

class MyObject {
  String? id;
  String name;
  String userId;
  ...
  MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    id = json['id'],
    ...
}

class AppUser {
  String? id;
  ...
}
```

I've brainstormed a few potential solutions, but I'm unsure of the best approach:

- Populate the id field by letting Firestore create the ID before adding the document, with final objRef = db.collection("my_objects").doc(); The downside is that I'd store the ID twice.
- After adding a document, set the MyObject.id to the ID Firestore returns. However, there's no guarantee the ID is set for MyObject instances.
- Remove the id field from MyObject and create a Map<String, MyObject>, storing the ID with MyObject instances.

Given the above solutions, are there other potential methods to handle this scenario? Which solution is preferable?
I'm grateful for every suggestion!

Any suggestions on which of these approaches is preferable? Or is there another solution I haven't considered? I'm grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you generate the document ID first, by calling the [doc()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) method on the [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html) object. This method returns an object of type [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) so you can use the [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/id.html) property within the class, which contains:

> The document's given ID within the collection.

As soon as the ID of the document is generated, which is an operation that is performed on the client and **not** on the server, then you can set the value of the ID inside the `myObject` object and perform the write operation in Firestore.

Comment: Thanks, this is also what I meant with the first item in my proposed solutions. So you recommend that I would store the id twice (Inside myObject and as the document id)?

Comment: As I understood from your question, you need the document ID inside the document itself, as you always got null. However, when reading the data you can always read the document ID. So you should store the document ID inside the document **only** if you need it.

Comment: I need it for any further modifications of the object in firebase (update, delete).

Comment: As long as you add the ID of the document inside `myObject` before writing the document to Fiestore, then there are no more updates needed because the document ID already exists there.

Comment: I know, I meant for updating other fields of `myObject` that are not included in my minimal example :)

Comment: If you have that data, you can add it as the document ID from the beginning or update it later.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me to make a decision between so I marked it as the solution. Thank you!